# building search function in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this view to search for name or telephone no.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/telephone/search')}}">
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Name or Telephone no.">
<input type="submit" class="btn-btn-default" value="search">
```

The route redirecting to this controller:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
  {
        $name=$request->get('search');
        $search=telephone::where('name','like',$name)
                         ->orWhere('Name','like',%$name)
                         ->orWhere('Name','like',$name%);
                            ->paginate(5);

        return view('telephone.searchview',['search'=>$search]);
}
```

which then supposed to show this view:

```
    <thead style='background-color:silver'><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>Name</td><td>Telephone No.</td><td>Mobile No.</td><td>Options</td></tr></thead>
@if($search==NULL)
No Results!
@else    
@foreach ($search as $li)
    <tr><td></td><td>{{$li->Name}}</td><td>{{$li->telephone}}</td><td>{{$li->mobile}}</td>
    <td>here</td></tr></table>
    @endforeach
    {!! $search->render() !!}
 @endif
```

got the error in orwhere syntax and also no results is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

This could be archived like this or maybe you have multiple column in your table

```
$search = telephone::where('name', 'LIKE', '%$name%')->get();
```

Comment: still problem if no results match.`@if($search==NULL) No Results! @else `

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
@if($search->count() == 0)
```

instead of

```
@if($search==NULL)
```

of course you should use proper where arguments, like

```
$search=telephone::where('Name','like','%'.$name.'%')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is on your syntax, which should be

```
$search=telephone::where('name','like',$name)
                         ->orWhere('Name','like', "%$name")
                         ->orWhere('Name','like', "$name%");
                         ->paginate(5);
```

Or clearer,

```
->orWhere('Name','like', "%{$name}")
```

Single quote

```
->orWhere('Name','like', '%'.$name)
```

---

Then, for the best approach. Simplifize your query as @abiodun's answered

```
$search = telephone::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%")->paginate(5);
```

Comment: still problem if no results matched.`@if($search==NULL)
No Results!
@else `

Comment: what does `dd($search)` showing on before returning the view?